# IBM mfp push notifications in status bar (Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-cloud, android-notification-bar, ibm-mobile-services

Hi i'm trying to show *Push Notifications in Android Status Bar*. I'm using **ibm-mfp-push plugin** and this code:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

          BMSClient.initialize("xxxxx","xxxxx");

        MFPPush.registerDevice({}, function(data){

            alert("Success ::" + data)
        }, function(error){
            alert("Failure ::" + error);
        }); 

        var notificationsCallback = function(notification){
            alert("Incoming notification :: " + JSON.stringify(notification))           
        };

        MFPPush.registerNotificationsCallback(notificationsCallback);

    }
```

I recieve notifications correctly but i have no idea how show this notifications in status bar. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: By status bar, are you referring to the notification shade? If the application is in background, does the notification appear in the shade?

Comment: Yes, i'm referring to the notification shade, sorry. If the application is in background notifications are not shown. Only when application is open notifications appear in alerts.

Comment: When the application is in background, and you dispatch a notification, do you see anything in logcat?

Comment: Sorry. I can't use in this Logcat in this moment. I think I receive notifications correctly, but any attempt to use plugins (local notifications) for notifications appear in the notification shade have been useless. I am only able to make them appear as alerts

Comment: Please provide context... what is your mfp version... what is "bms"...

Comment: Slightly confused as to what exactly you're asking for. If the application is in the foreground you will not receive a notification in your notification shade, you'll receive an alert instead. If the application is in the background when the notification is received it should show in the notification shade / status bar with a star icon (default). Is this not the case?

Answer (score 1):

In case you application was running when remote notification arrived it will not be displayed automatically in notification shade since it will be immediately processed by application. You will see notification in the notification shade only incase application was not running when notification has arrived.

That said, you can add you own logic to add items to notification shade once remote notification was received. You need to add this logic in your notificationsCallback. You can use an existing local-notifications plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification) or implement it on your own with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

Answer (score 1):

I already found the solution.
Sorry if I was unclear on the question. My problem was that I could not get notifications appear in the notification shade.

When the application is in the foreground notifications appears to me as if javascript alert and when the application is in the background nothing appears until put in the foreground.

I tried to use various local notification plugins but when the event onDeviceReady is fullfiled these plugins are not loaded.

For those who do not know the plugin I leave some documentation: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-mfp-push](http://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-mfp-push)

The solution is to add in the onDeviceReady event this:

*CDVMFPPush.setIgnoreIncomingNotifications(boolean ignore);* (being ignore == true)

That function is described in documentation as:

> By default, push notifications plugin handles all incoming Push
>   Notification by tunneling them to JavaScript callback. Use this method
>   to override the plugin's default behavior in case you want to manually
>   handle incoming push notifications in native code.

BMSClient is a singleton that serves as an entry point to bluemix client-server communication. In my case I use it to initialize the client especifying two parameters:

*BMSClient.initialize("APPROUTE","APPGUID");*

Thank you for your answers. Happy to belong to this great community.

regards